# SQL SELECT query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got two tables, `Document` and `DocumentField` defined as below.

**Document** (relevant columns only for brevity):

```
DocumentKey - char(36)
DocTypeKey - char(36)
```

**DocumentField**:

```
DocumentKey - char(36)
FieldId - varchar(10)
FieldValue - varchar(255)
```

`DocumentKey` and `DocTypeKey` values are standard GUIDs. `FieldId` is primarily a string value of the numbers 1 through 30 (there are several other non-numeric values hence why it is a `varchar` column). `FieldValue` is just a string value, could be anything.

Sample data for `Document` would be:

```
DocKey | DocTypeKey  
A      | X  
B      | Y  
C      | Z
```

Sample data in `DocumentField` would be:

```
DocKey | FieldId | FieldValue  
A      | 1       | PO1234  
A      | 2       | INV1234  
B      | 1       | PO5678  
B      | 2       | INV5678 
C      | 1       | PO1234
C      | 2       | INV2345
```

The query I'm trying to run is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Document 
INNER JOIN DocumentField ON Document.DocumentKey = DocumentField.DocumentKey 
WHERE  (DocTypeKey IS NOT NULL) AND (FieldId = '1' AND FieldValue LIKE 'PO1%') AND (FieldId = '2' AND FieldValue LIKE 'INV1%')
```

But I'm not getting results when I add the `AND (FieldId = '2' AND FieldValue LIKE 'INV%')` portion. It works fine with just the first `WHERE  (DocTypeKey IS NOT NULL) AND (FieldId = '1' AND FieldValue LIKE 'PO%')` portion. Given the sample data above I'd want it to return:

```
DocKey | DocTypeKey
A      | X
```

Is there an easy way I can get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: I should clarify. I'm looking for all documents with a `DocTypeKey` and BOTH `(FieldId = '1' AND FieldValue LIKE 'PO1%')` AND `(FieldId = '2' AND FieldValue LIKE 'INV1%')`. An OR will not meet the requirements of the search.

Comment: You'll need something like a sub-select.  Take a look at my answer below - it will give you the result you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. What I ended up with was sort of along the same lines as Brian S and millimoose's answers, using subselects for each additional criteria.

```
SELECT Document.* 
FROM Document 
INNER JOIN DocumentField ON Document.DocumentKey = DocumentField.DocumentKey 
WHERE  (DocTypeKey IS NOT NULL) 
AND Document.DocumentKey IN (
    SELECT DocumentKey FROM DocumentField WHERE FieldId = '1' AND FieldValue  LIKE 'PO1%' 
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT DocumentKey FROM DocumentField WHERE FieldId = '2' AND FieldValue  LIKE 'INV1%'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check each document with a subquery. The best I could come up with is this:

```
select d.* from Document d
where d.DocTypeKey is not null
and (
    select count(*) = 2 from DocumentField df
    where df.DocKey = d.DocKey
    and (
        (df.FieldId = '1' and df.FieldValue like 'PO1%')
        or (df.FieldId = '2' and df.FieldValue like 'INV1%')));
```

where in `count(*) = 2` you have to use the number of `FieldId`+`FieldValue` conditions in the subselect.

Here's an ideone sample with your data: http://ideone.com/uURwu. ideone uses SQLite and I developed this in H2, but the SQL Server syntax should be the same.

Comment: The thing is, we don't want an `OR` condition, we want both of the `FieldId`/`FieldValue` conditions to be true, which is the wrench in this whole thing unfortunately.

Comment: @Kettch19 Oh, you want a DOCUMENT that has rows that satisfy both conditions, not just the fields.

Comment: @Kettch19 I rewrote my answer.

Comment: @Kettch19 Actually, this might break if a document can have multiple fields with the same `FieldId`. Can this happen, or is `(DocKey, FieldId)` unique? If not this will probably require a bunch of `EXISTS` subselects.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want OR (FieldId = '2' AND FieldValue LIKE 'INV1%')

you can't have FieldId = '1'   AND FieldId = '2'

Comment: Note the results he's looking for, an OR won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
WHERE  (DocTypeKey IS NOT NULL) 
AND ((FieldId = '1' AND FieldValue LIKE 'PO1%') OR (FieldId = '2' AND FieldValue LIKE 'INV1%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers state, you can't have a row where FieldId = '1' AND FieldId = '2'.

However, I'm going to disagree with the other answers use of OR instead - you seem to want to find the single Document row that has both FieldId of 1 and 2 with the appropriate FieldValues.  So the OR won't get you what you want - you'll need to use a sub-select:

```
SELECT Document.DocKey, Document.DocTypeKey
FROM Document 
INNER JOIN DocumentField ON Document.DocKey = DocumentField.DocKey 
WHERE  Document.DocTypeKey IS NOT NULL 
  AND DocumentField.FieldId = '1' AND DocumentField.FieldValue LIKE 'PO1%'
  AND  Document.DocKey = (SELECT DocumentField.DocKey FROM DocumentField WHERE DocumentField.FieldId = '2' AND DocumentField.FieldValue LIKE 'INV1%')
```

Comment: The last condition will probably break if more than one document has a matching field - the subselect will return a tuple of `DocKey`s.

Comment: You are right @millimoose - was just trying to give an example of how to use a sub-select to get the desired result given the dataset in the question.